# ORA-01810: format code appears twice in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Why is the SQL below generating an `ORA-01810` error? I trying to get the records between particular dates.

```
select * 
from transaction 
where txn_date between TO_DATE('01-07-2018 10:19:51 AM', 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss a') 
                   and TO_DATE('10-07-2018 04:58:15 PM', 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss a');
```

Comment: You used the code for month twice, `MM` is the same as `mm`, you probably want `mi` for minutes. See [Oracle / PLSQL: ORA-01810 Error Message](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01810.php) for more information.

Comment: The format code for minutes is `mi`

Comment: i tried your suggestions but getting like `ORA-01821: date format not recognized`

Comment: Show the format you have now then.

Comment: `TO_DATE('10-07-2018 04:58:15 PM', 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mi:ss am')` -- not `a`, it should be `am`

Comment: Please make sure you [read the documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php).

Answer (score 0):

The code for minutes is not `mm`, it is `mi`.  You need to spell out `am`.  So:

```
TO_DATE('01-07-2018 10:19:51 AM', 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mi:ss AM')
```